# Java Swing: How to be notified if tool tip is about to become visible?

Tags: java, swing

I have a lot of components that set tool tips with `JComponent.setToolTipText(...)`.  However, these tool tips change often based on many events.  I could make a setToolTipText(...) call each time one of these events occur; but I would much prefer to simply have a tool tip listener that notifies me when a tip is about to show, so that I can update the tip, if needed.  I can't find anyway to assign a listener to the tool tip, am I missing one?

*Note, my solution needs to be Java 1.4.2 compliant.

Comment: *"..my solution needs to be Java 1.4.2 compliant."*  You do realize that 1.4 is obsolete, don't you?  And if your reply to that is that you have clients using 1.4, I'll point out that there comes a time when supporting older JREs will cost you more than those clients can generate in income.

Comment: That is my response, and your point is very valid.  However, I am a lowly developer and do not make these decisions.

Comment: there are exist options create onw ToolTip by yourself, it doesn't matter if for Java1.4 or Java1.6, because I think that from Java1.4 there isn't any changes for this dinosaurus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually found a decent solution: override `JComponent.getToolTipText()`.

One disturbing nuance to this, this is the code from JComponent.setToolTipText():

```
  public void setToolTipText(String text) {
        String oldText = getToolTipText();
        putClientProperty(TOOL_TIP_TEXT_KEY, text);
        ToolTipManager toolTipManager = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
        if (text != null) {
        if (oldText == null) {
                toolTipManager.registerComponent(this);
        }
        } else {
            toolTipManager.unregisterComponent(this);
        }
    }
```

So, if you override getToolTipText to return some dynamic value, it better return null the first time it is called, or your tool tip will not get registered with the ToolTipManager.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is an easy way to be notified of this event.  However, it sounds like you might need to change your design.  Having to update a large number of components with constantly changing tool tips seems odd and problematic.  Maybe just add a generic MouseListener that determines the message for the current component at the current time.  That will get you away from having to constantly change all components.

Answer (score 0):

Override the JComponent's createToolTip() this will act as a listener, whenever a tooltip is about to be created, this method is called.